# Crystal Report Layout Printing Sections Different

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to add a new Details sections after my Account ID section (Details e). My new section seems to always get printed before the Account ID section, no matter that I insert it after my Account Id section (see images for more details)

[image: Design view]

[image: Report output]

Answer (score 0):

In first place, the order of the data/records determines when what it is printed.

If you want to print information of the same record in different sections, then the section order is relevant.

So you have to make sure that the **sorting** and **grouping** inside the report brings the data in the desired order.